# Magento2 : Admin order creation should auto select specific shipping method?

Tags: magento2, admin, backend

In magento version 2.2, when admin is creating an order, I want to **automatically select shipping method (Flatrate)** without manual selection.

I tried adding the following commands (**order.loadShippingRates()** and **order.setShippingMethod('flatrate')**) to the button **"Add Selected Products To Order"**.
This caused the the product to disappear in the product selection list and the shipping method to load without any selection.

Comment: Hello , Have you find solution for this issue?